# Linear relation between batch size and inference time per batch

Tags: python, runtime, pytorch, inference

I made the following observation which I can not follow. I am using the deeplabv3_resnet50 model from torchvision and run it in eval mode with different batch sizes. The runtime including a torch.synchronize() are almost linear with the batch size. That means that the rate of images/second is almost constant. I also tried out different settings of cudnn.benchnmark = True/False. I was hoping to see a constant inference time per batch over all batch sizes because they are running in parallel on the gpu. Am I getting anything wrong here?

2 - 0.02s

4 - 0.031s

8 - 0.05s

16 - 0.094s

32 - 0.178s

relevant code:

```
           with torch.no_grad():
                inputs, side_data = self.create_input(sample) # inputs.to(device) happens in here
                torch.cuda.synchronize()
                labels = sample["label"]
                start = time.time()
                outputs = self.model(inputs)
                torch.cuda.synchronize()
                print(time.time() - start)
                preds = torch.argmax(outputs, 1)
```

Thanks for your help.
Markus

torch=1.4.0, CUDA Version: 10.0, Tesla V100

Comment: Could you do some further measurements? Like `tensor.cuda()` and `tensor.cpu()` , only on `forward` etc.? Could you provide relevant part of your source code?

Comment: I added the code to the initial post. Do you mean running it on cpu? I tried before and runtimes are a lot longer.